# MaterialUI DesktopDatePicker change year range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

I wanted to ask if there is a way of changing the range of years in the calendar so it goes 20 by 20 years. Now it's like this:

[image]

And i want it like this:

[image]

The actual code is this:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <DesktopDatePicker
            animateYearScrolling
            components={{
                OpenPickerIcon: CalendarMonth
            }}
            views={['year']}
            onChange={value => setDate(value)} value={date}
            renderInput={(params) =>
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    name={'year'}
                    inputProps={{...params.inputProps, placeholder: 'Enter a year'}}
                    helperText={null}
                />
            }
            openTo={'year'}
            minDate={dayjs(new Date(`${minYear}-1-1`))}
            maxDate={dayjs(new Date(`${maxYear}-1-1`))}
            ToolbarComponent={() => <CalendarMonth/>}
        />
    </LocalizationProvider>
```